# Swift: "Ambiguous reference to member" init

Tags: swift, xcode

There are several posts on this subject, but I can't see the answer to this problem in them. The following lines produce the title error:

```
let pdf_url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: inputfile)
let pdf_doc = PDFDocument.init?(url: pdf_url) as! URL
```

I understand that the init method can take a variety of data types, but surely I've made it pretty clear that I want a URL.

Error message is:

```
error: ambiguous reference to member 'init(url:)'
```

A problem which may be related is that Xcode occasionally tells me to use URL, not NSURL, in the first line, but then complains that URL doesn't have the fileURL method. 
(I also tried CGPDFDocument, but that wanted a CFURL, and wouldn't accept NSURL, even though they are supposed to be "toll-free bridged".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you (try to) cast PDFDocument to URL.

You probably mean

```
PDFDocument.init?(url: pdf_url as! URL)
```

But the recommended Swift 3 syntax is

```
let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: inputfile) // returns a non-optional URL
let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)
```

Please use – Swift – camel case variable names rather than – javascript / php – snake case.

Comment: Apple's documentation says to use init, and init is needed in similar scripts in other languages. How do I tell that it's not the case?

Comment: `PDFDocument(url` and `PDFDocument.init?(url` are synonyms.

Comment: *synonym* means identical. Yes they will, but Apple suggests to use the simpler form.

Comment: I think Xcode's Fix-it told me to put that in, possibly as the result of some other error. Again, it's in the documentation. But ok, so without the question mark, they're synonymous. Where does Apple say to use the simpler form?

Comment: The documentation shows the method **declaration**. The way to use it can be different. I don't know any Apple sample code which uses `.init` explicitly, that implies to use the simpler form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `URL`:

```
let pdf_url = URL(fileURLWithPath: inputfile)
```

Comment: @benwiggy because you didn't create pdf correctly and accordingly `PDFDocument(url:pdf_url)`

Comment: Ah yes. As in the other comment. Note my reply there. Apple's docs say to use the init method.